# Why timeout is not working

Tags: php, timeout

sorry for stupid question, but
Im trying to set the timeout for program called cirsym. Because sometimes Im facing with infinity process and I have to cancel the operation using ssh...
Would be really thankfull if someone help...

```
<?

/**
 * Execute a command and return it's output. Either wait until the command exits or the timeout has expired.
 *
 * @param string $cmd Command to execute.
 * @param number $timeout Timeout in seconds.
 * @return string Output of the command.
 * @throws \Exception
 */
function exec_timeout($cmd, $timeout) {
// File descriptors passed to the process.

    $descriptors = array(
        0 => array('pipe', 'r'), // stdin
        1 => array('pipe', 'w'), // stdout
        2 => array('pipe', 'w') // stderr
        );

// Start the process.

    $process = proc_open('exec ' . $cmd, $descriptors, $pipes);

    if (!is_resource($process)) {
        throw new \Exception('Could not execute process');
    }

// Set the stdout stream to none-blocking.

    stream_set_blocking($pipes[1], 0);

// Turn the timeout into microseconds.

    $timeout = $timeout * 1000000;

// Output buffer.

    $buffer = '';

// While we have time to wait.

    while ($timeout > 0) {
        $start = microtime(true);

// Wait until we have output or the timer expired.

        $read = array($pipes[1]);
        $other = array();
        stream_select($read, $other, $other, 0, $timeout);

// Get the status of the process.
// Do this before we read from the stream,
// this way we can't lose the last bit of output if the process dies between these functions.

        $status = proc_get_status($process);

// Read the contents from the buffer.
// This function will always return immediately as the stream is none-blocking.

        $buffer .= stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);

        if (!$status['running']) {
            break;
        }

// Subtract the number of microseconds that we waited.

        $timeout -= (microtime(true) - $start) * 1000000;
    }

// Check if there were any errors.

    $errors = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);

    if (!empty($errors)) {
        throw new \Exception($errors);
    }

// Kill the process in case the timeout expired and it's still running.
// If the process already exited this won't do anything.

    proc_terminate($process, 9);

    // Close all streams.

    fclose($pipes[0]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[2]);

    proc_close($process);

    return $buffer;
}
This is the function



private function Exec(){
    if(shell_exec($this->canonical_path."cirsym_v2.1.bin") != NULL)
    {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like PHP, not C or C++.

Comment: I'm not sure that `stream_set_blocking()` affects `stream_get_contents()`, since it's defined to keep reading until it gets to EOF.

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/1/timeout

Comment: Thx, but I need to set timeout forever not write it every time